# Placing one object in front of another in Corona SDK

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I am building a platform jumper, and when the ball passes through the platform, I would like it to appear in front, not behind, the platform.  I've tried putting both objects into a new dispaly group in the proper order and sending the ball to the front using `toFront()`, but I just can't get it to work.  Any thoughts?

```
local ball = display.newCircle( 100, 100, 30 )
ball.id = "ball"
ball.x, ball.y = 160, 350
ball.rotation = 15

local gradient = {
    type="gradient",
    color1={ 1, 4, 7 }, color2={ .1, 1, 1.5}, direction="down"
                }
ball:setFillColor( gradient )

-- add physics to the ball
physics.addBody( ball, "dynamic", { density=1.0,
                friction=0.9, bounce=0 } )

-- create a platform w/ physics
local bottom = display.newRect( 0, 0, 320, 100 )
bottom.anchorX = 0
bottom.anchorY = 1
bottom.x, bottom.y = 0, display.contentHeight

physics.addBody( bottom, "static", { friction=0.3 } )

-- put plat in middle
local platform = display.newRect( 0, 0, screenW-100, screenH-450 )
platform.x, platform.y = 160, 200
platform.collType = "passthru"
physics.addBody( platform, "static", { bounce=0.0, friction=0.3 } )

-- place ball in front
local group = display.newGroup( )
group:insert( ball )
group:insert( platform )

ball:toFront( )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your putting the ball in the wrong order, it should be

```
local group = display.newGroup( )
group:insert( platform )
group:insert( ball )
```

Take a look at [Group Hierarchy](http://docs.coronalabs.com/daily/guide/graphics/group.html)